Row like div inside a flex environment with a rotated heading at the beginning
Goal
Eventually I want to get something like this (forget about the white border around this is due to the clipping):

Constraints
This elements must sit within the following markup which I cannot change easily:
<div style="position:absolute;top:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;left:15px">
  <div style="display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;width:100%;height:100%;">
     <div style="position:relative;-webkit-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;">
          <!-- place elements here -->
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

What I tried
<div class="split-container">
  <div class="split-heading">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="split-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

.split-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.split-heading {
  background-color: rgb(198,89,17);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px; /* Add padding to the sides */
}

.split-heading > h3 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.split-content {
  flex-grow: 100;
  background-color: rgb(244,176,132);
  color: #fff;
}

Result
https://codepen.io/thothal/pen/qBwxEKO

Issues

The heading div should only take the needed space (it is too broad right now)
The heading should vertically and horizontally centered
The content should be vertically centered


Solution:

You can use the css writing-mode property to display the text vertically, then rotate it 180 degrees, to flip it. Then set margin to 0px (because <h3> tags have already a margin).
Add a display: flex, align-items: center to the split-heading class to center it.
Add a display: flex, align-items: center to the split-content class to center it.



.split-container {
  display: flex;
}

.split-heading {
  background-color: rgb(198,89,17);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px; /* Add padding to the sides */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.split-heading > h3 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  margin: 0px;
}

.split-content {
  flex-grow: 100;
  background-color: rgb(244,176,132);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
<div style="position:absolute;top:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;left:15px">
  <div style="display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;width:100%;height:100%;">
     <div style="position:relative;-webkit-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;">
          <div class="split-container">
            <div class="split-heading">
              <h3>Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="split-content">
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>




Using writing-mode: tb-rl ->


.split-container {
  display: flex;
}

.split-heading {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background-color: rgb(198,89,17);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px; /* Add padding to the sides */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.split-heading > h3 {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  margin: 15px;
}

.split-content {
  flex-grow: 100;
  background-color: rgb(244,176,132);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.split-content p {
margin-left: 10px;
}
<div style="position:absolute;top:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;left:15px">
  <div style="display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;width:100%;height:100%;">
     <div style="position:relative;-webkit-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;">
          <div class="split-container">
            <div class="split-heading">
              <h3>Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="split-content">
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>




You did very well !
and if your adding this code at your classes , its done :
.split-content { align-items: center }

and this :
.split-header { justify-content: center; align-items: center }


You just need to give .split-heading & .split-content, display: flex; then use align-items: center; to vertically center the their contents. You can use justify-content: center; to horizontally center the h3 within the .split-heading and remove transform-origin: bottom right;


.split-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.split-heading {
  background-color: rgb(198, 89, 17);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;

  width: 2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.split-heading > h3 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.split-content {
  flex-grow: 100;
  background-color: rgb(244, 176, 132);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
<div style="position:absolute;top:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;left:15px">
  <div style="display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div style="position:relative;-webkit-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1;width:100%;height:100%;">
      <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;">

        <div class="split-container">
          <div class="split-heading">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="split-content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




If you change your css to:
.split-heading {
  background-color: rgb(198, 89, 17);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px; /* Add padding to the sides */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.split-heading > h3 {
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
  text-align: center;
}

.split-content {
  flex-grow: 100;
  background-color: rgb(244, 176, 132);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

Basically: add flex display to the elements with align-items: center, so you are able to center the elements in the div vertically.
